# How easy is it to create false evidence for a biased coin?

Tags: probability, statistics, statistical-inference, random-walk

I have a biased coin which comes up heads with probability $p$. I know the value of $p$, but I want to falsely claim that the coin has a different probability of heads, $q$, where $q > p$.

To support my claim I decide to produce some false evidence: I flip the coin repeatedly and record the fraction of flips that were heads, and keep flipping until the fraction is at least $q$. I also make sure I flip the coin at least $100$ times before stopping (so I flip $100$ times initially, then I keep flipping until the fraction of heads so far is at least $q$). I report the total number of flips, and the fraction of heads, as evidence that the coin has probability of heads (approximately) $q$.

1. In terms of $p$ and $q$, what is the probability that I can successfully produce evidence for my false claim? (I.e. what is the probability that after $100$ initial flips, my repeated flipping will eventually terminate with a fraction above $q$ in a finite amount of time?)
2. Given that I do successfully produce the false evidence, what is the expected number of flips required?

---

I thought of this question out of curiosity, when pondering about how we can soundly use data to infer unknown probabilities.

For Question 1, the probability is positive: in fact, it's at least $p^{100}$ since the first $100$ flips could all be heads. It's less clear if the probability is $< 1$, but I think it is. The question can be phrased as a random walk in two dimensions, where the false evidence is produced if the random walk enters into the region of points $(x,y)$ where $y > q \cdot (x + y) \text{ and } x + y \ge 100$.

For Question 2, probably thinking about it as a random walk is also the first step.

**For either question, I would be happy with upper/lower bounds or approximations, if an exact answer is not easy.**

Comment: The answer to (2) would be infinite if $q=p$ so it would be curious if it was not infinite for $q \gt p$

Comment: @Henry Why is it infinite for $q=p$?

Comment: JairTaylor: For example with a balanced 1-D $\pm1$ random walk, the expected time of the first return to $0$ is infinite

Comment: @Henry: I don't think that would be curious. We're conditioning on actually achieving $q$. For $q=p$, this can be achieved arbitrarily late, but for $q\gt p$ it becomes very unlikely over time, so the conditional expectation could be dominated by the early opportunities and be finite.

Comment: @joriki - digging deeper suggests that you may well be correct, though I still find that result to be curious

Comment: I wonder whether [Hoeffding's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoeffding%27s_inequality) helps for 1. Let $S_n$ denote the number of heads after $n$ flips. This is a series of Bernoulli trials with parameter $p$. We have $E(S_n)=pn$. Hoeffding's inequality yields (see the "Proof" section for the statement) $$ P(S_n\geq qn) = P\big(S_n-E(S_n)\geq qn-pn\big) \leq
\exp\big(-2n^2(q-p)^2\big). $$

Comment: @StephanKolassa Good idea -- I think that summing up those bounds does give a bound on (1). It might fail to give a bound if $(q - p)$ is too small, if my math is correct. How did you get the $n^2$ in the bound? the section under "Special case of Bernoulli random variables" gives a bound $\exp(-2 (q - p)^2 n)$, with $n$ instead of $n^2$.

Comment: Yes, sorry, it should be $n$ - taking the formula right above "Usage", we divide by a sum that evaluates to $n$, so we can cancel of of the $n^2$ in the numerator, leaving only an $n$ term. I don't know whether this can simply be summed; after all, the process is heavily dependent. Anyway, I linked here from the CrossValidated chat, maybe someone will drop by. Looking for "proportions of success in a Bernoulli process" and similar didn't give me anything.

Comment: @StephanKolassa I think it can be summed (although the result is a very course overapproximation) -- this is by the Union Bound

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## A few thoughts on your question 1

The number $S_n$ of heads after $n$ flips follows a standard [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) with parameters $n$ and $p$. Alternatively, the sequence $(S_n)$ is a [Bernoulli process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_process).

---

### A larger lower bound

We can use this to somewhat sharpen the lower bound of $p^{100}$ you give in your question. Namely, while getting 100 successes in the first 100 trials (let's set $n_0=100$) is sufficient, so would be getting only $\lceil qn_0\rceil$. The probability for this is the upper tail probability of our binomial distribution,

$$ P(S_{n_0}\geq qn_0) =
\sum_{k=\lceil qn_0\rceil}^{n_0}{n\choose k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}. $$

Now, [Wikipedia tells us](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Tail_bounds) (quoting chapter 11 of *Elements of Information Theory* by Cover and Thomas, which I admittedly haven't looked at) that

$$P(S_n\geq k) \geq \frac{1}{n+1}\exp\bigg(-nD\Big(\frac{k}{n}\,||\,p\Big)\bigg)
\text{ if }p<\frac{k}{n}<1, $$
where
$$ D\Big(\frac{k}{n}\,||\,p\Big) = \frac{k}{n}\ln\frac{k}{np}+\Big(1-\frac{k}{n}\Big)\ln\frac{1-\frac{k}{n}}{1-p} $$
is the relative entropy between the $\frac{k}{n}$-coin and the $p$-coin. We note that with $k=\lceil qn_0\rceil$ with $q>p$, the condition $p<\frac{k}{n_0}=\frac{\lceil qn_0\rceil}{n_0}<1$ is satisfied, so we get a lower bound for your probability (resulting solely from the probability of having enough successes in the inital $n_0$ flips of)

$$ \begin{align*}
&\frac{1}{n_0+1}\exp\bigg(-n_0D\Big(\frac{\lceil qn_0\rceil}{n_0}\,||\,p\Big)\bigg) \\
=& \frac{1}{n_0+1}\exp\bigg(-n_0\frac{\lceil qn_0\rceil}{n_0}\ln\frac{\lceil qn_0\rceil}{n_0p}-n_0\Big(1-\frac{\lceil qn_0\rceil}{n_0}\Big)\ln\frac{1-\frac{\lceil qn_0\rceil}{n_0}}{1-p}\bigg) \\
=& \frac{1}{n_0+1}\bigg(\frac{\lceil qn_0\rceil}{n_0p}\bigg)^{-\lceil qn_0\rceil}
\bigg(\frac{1-\frac{\lceil qn_0\rceil}{n_0}}{1-p}\bigg)^{\lceil qn_0\rceil-n_0},
\end{align*} $$
which should be larger than $p^{100}$ - for instance, if $p=0.4$ and $q=0.5$, then $p^{100}\approx\exp(-91.6)\approx 1.6\times 10^{-40}$, while this expression comes out to about $\exp(-6.7)\approx 0.0013$.

---

### An upper bound

Next, as noted in [a comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3235793/how-easy-is-it-to-create-false-evidence-for-a-biased-coin#comment7544099_3235793), [Hoeffding's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoeffding%27s_inequality) may be helpful. We have $E(S_n)=pn$, and Hoeffding's inequality yields (see the "Proof" section for the statement) that
$$ P(S_n>qn) = P(S_n-E(S_n)\geq qn-pn) \leq\exp\big(-2n(q-p)^2\big). $$

As  [you write](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3235793/how-easy-is-it-to-create-false-evidence-for-a-biased-coin#comment7544575_3235793), we can use the [union bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boole's_inequality) to get a very crude bound on the probability we are interested in:
$$ \begin{align*}
& P(\exists n\geq n_0\colon S_n\geq qn) \\
\leq & \sum_{n=n_0}^\infty P(S_n>qn) \text{ by the union bound} \\
\leq & \sum_{n=n_0}^\infty \exp\big(-2n(q-p)^2\big) \text{ by Hoeffding, above} \\
= & \sum_{n=n_0}^\infty \Big(\underbrace{\exp\big(-2(q-p)^2\big)}_{=:x}\Big)^n \\
= & \frac{x^{n_0}}{1-x}\text{ as a geometric series} \\
= & \frac{\exp\big(-2n_0(q-p)^2\big)}{1-\exp\big(-2(q-p)^2\big)}.
\end{align*} $$

As an example, for $p=0.4$ and $q=0.5$ as above, this comes to about $6.83$. Hum. It gets more useful for larger $q$, e.g., $q=0.6$ yields a bound of about $0.0044$.

---

Finally, here is a little simulation. I simulated 100,000 trajectories of our Bernoulli process with $p=0.4$ and calculated the running success probabilities $(\frac{S_n}{n})$. Below, I plot 10 random trajectories, as well as the trajectory of the maximum of our 100,000 running probabilities. The initial $n_0=100$ steps are plotted in gray. I also included a horizontal line at $q=0.5$ in red. It seems like the initial steps dominate the question. (Incidentally, out of our 100,000 trajectories, 2,682 had a quotient of $\frac{S_{n_0}}{n_0}\geq 0.5$ after the initial $n_0=100$ steps, where the bound above would have predicted at least 130.)

[image: trajectories]

R code:

```
pp <- 0.4
qq <- 0.5
n_0 <- 100

# the original lower bound:
100*log(pp)

# the larger lower bound 
-log(n_0+1)-
ceiling(qq*n_0)*log(ceiling(qq*n_0)/(pp*n_0))+
(ceiling(qq*n_0)-n_0)*log((1-ceiling(qq*n_0)/n_0)/(1-pp))

# the overall upper bound from from Hoeffding's inequality and the union bound
exp(-2*n_0*(qq-pp)^2)/(1-exp(-2*(qq-pp)^2))

# the simulation
n_sims <- 1e5
sim_length <- 2e3
initial_length <- 100
set.seed(1)

sims <- matrix(runif(n_sims*sim_length)<pp,nrow=sim_length)
running_quotient <- apply(sims,2,cumsum)/matrix(1:sim_length,nrow=sim_length,ncol=n_sims)

plot(c(1,sim_length),range(running_quotient),type="n",xlab="Step",ylab="Proportion of successes",las=1)
for ( ii in 1:10 ) {
    lines(1:sim_length,running_quotient[,ii],col="gray30")
    lines(1:initial_length,running_quotient[1:initial_length,ii],col="gray80")
}
lines(1:sim_length,apply(running_quotient,1,max),lwd=2)
lines(1:initial_length,apply(running_quotient,1,max)[1:initial_length],lwd=2,col="gray70")
abline(h=qq,col="red")

sum(running_quotient[100,]>=qq)
```